# No title bar, window bored or unity launcher in 12.10 after xrandr

Tags: 12.10, unity, launcher, xrandr, titlebar

-hey guys, need some serious help.
Yesterday I was playing around with xrandr to try to get an HDMI TV to work properly without having over scan/ under scan as I have an Intel graphic chip and could not use the control centre.

All was fine, but after booting into Ubuntu today, after the login screen all I see is my desktop background and my mouse, no top title bar, or launcher. I can open up terminal using ctrl alt t and can run programs through there but need to get this fixed! Any suggestions as I don't know where I've gone wring.

Thanks

Comment: Braiam - great advice - saved my bacon!!! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

bug
[Ubuntu Bug 1166765 -unity showing only blank desktop, no dash nor decorations](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1166765)

The tmp fix is to open a terminal, if you don't have a terminal icon on desktop, then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> login and then execute the following command:

```
$ gsettings reset org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ active-plugins
$ sudo shutdown -r now
```