# command line, no desktop environment

Tags: command-line, 12.04, system-installation

I have installed an ubuntu in a computer with windows, but when i open the computer with ubuntu, there's no desktop environment, only a command line.
I've even written my username and password on command line but it's still just a command line.

Extra info: when I choose `try ubuntu` with usb booting, there is no desktop neither. I have no internet connection on this computer for instance.

- I've written the code with lightdm, the screen is full of "starting" and "stopping" different things such as "lightdm display manager" or "save kernel messages". Only "stopping anac(h)ronistic cron" fail others ok. still no desktop.
- I added `nomodeset` and second time `modeset=0` in the gnu grub screen. ctrl-x didn't work but i could have boot with f10 (it was written below the screen). Both didn't do any change.

When I tried to set them permanently as in the forum: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132 gksudo gave me an error message.

By the way when I'm opening the computer windows is directly opened if I don't press on esc to enter boot options by f9. I read that it can be because of number of parts more than 4 in hard disk.

Comment: Can you tell us the name of the file you downloaded?

Comment: Also, how did you installed? Using Wubi or you created a partition?

Comment: I downloaded ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso
I created a partition, before starting installation it asked me if I would like to overwrite on windows or make a partition.

no problem in usb, because it works in another computer, it might be something about bios configurations of the computer?

Comment: when i try directly from usb i have a command line as:
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.8.0-29-generic x86_64)
 * Documentation: https:/help.ubuntu.com/

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ _

Comment: When you are in the command line, can you do `sudo service lightdm start`? If it fails, please, edit your question and write the results.

Comment: there are also skipped non existing files

Comment: Could you take a picture then?

Comment: sorry, i can't. but i can write it down:
Repeat this process for the rest of the CDs in your set
W: Skipping non existent file /cdrom/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/packages
W: Skipping nonexistent file /cdrom/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/packages
W: Skipping nonexistent file /cdrom/dists/precise/restricted/binary-amd64/packages
W: Skipping nonexistent file /cdrom/dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/packages

Comment: Adding 'diversion of /usr/bin/bluetooth-applet to usr/bin/bluetooth-applet.orig by casper'
*Starting mDNS/DNS-SD daemon
*Starting bluetooth daemon
*Starting load fallback graphic devices
*Stopping load fallback graphic devices
*Starting configure network device security
*Starting Uncomplicated firewall

Comment: *Starting configure network device
*Starting configure network device security
*Starting Mount network filesystem
*Starting Failsafe Boot Delay
*Starting CUPS printing spooler/server
*Starting Mount network filesystem

Comment: sorry the last one was stopping instead of starting
*Starting Bridge socket events into upstart
*Starting configure network device
*Stopping Failsafe Boot Delay
*Starting System V initialisation compatibility
*Starting modem connection manager
*Starting configure network device security
*Starting network connection manager

Comment: Ok, forget about that, have you ran `sudo service lightdm start` and **just that**? The other looks like a boot log and is not interesting right now.

Comment: yes i wrote it, and clicked on enter. that's what i get

Comment: Please, **STOP**, I just asked you to run `sudo service lightdm start` and that's no output of that command! Just start Ubuntu from your hard drive, log in, and type `sudo service lightdm start`. **What you are commenting is not helpful to solve your problem!**

Comment: ok, sorry.
i've done it and got a similar screen with less lines. last line is "mountall: disconnected from plymouth"

Comment: When you boot up, press the shift key before it start Ubuntu, it should show a screen like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1Djlc.png). Press the `e` key. Then look for the line that starts with `linux` and ends with `splash quiet` and add at the end `nomodeset`, like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4tbVO.png). Now press Ctrl + X. If it boots alright then report back, if it doesn't then use `modeset=0`. Edit your question and report back your findings. You can use more options to try, just read this [forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132) for ideas.

Comment: Did you tried this http://askubuntu.com/a/284985/169736 ? Or this one http://askubuntu.com/a/202020/169736 ?

Answer (score 0):

I always accomplish setting up desktop by doing this right after installation:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get -y install ubuntu-desktop
```

Viola!

Comment: I changed UEFI to Legacy from by BIOS boot configuration, now it works! thank you very much Braiam